# In RestKit, how to force the local database to match the remote "master" dataset

Tags: ios, synchronization, restkit

Is there an easy way to force RestKit to delete old local items whenever it is synced with the "Master" remote dataset?

So essentially deleting elements not found in the new dataset?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using RestKit 0.10, I just added:

```
[objectManager.mappingProvider setObjectMapping:eventsMapping
                         forResourcePathPattern:@"data.xml"
                          withFetchRequestBlock:^NSFetchRequest *(NSString *resourcePath) {
                              return [Events fetchRequest];
                          }];
```

To my existing code. Now on update, any objects removed on the server, are removed from RestKit's managedObjects.

Here is the whole sequence:

```
// Set up the opjectManager
objectManager = [RKObjectManager objectManagerWithBaseURLString:kBaseUrlString];
objectManager.client.disableCertificateValidation = YES; // Using self signed cert
objectManager.client.cachePolicy = RKRequestCachePolicyLoadIfOffline | 
                                   RKRequestCachePolicyTimeout | 
                                   RKRequestCachePolicyLoadOnError | 
                                   RKRequestCachePolicyEtag;
objectManager.client.requestCache.storagePolicy = RKRequestCacheStoragePolicyPermanently;
objectManager.client.requestQueue.showsNetworkActivityIndicatorWhenBusy = YES;

// Set up the objectStore
RKManagedObjectStore* objectStore = [RKManagedObjectStore 
    objectStoreWithStoreFilename:databaseName 
           usingSeedDatabaseName:seedDatabaseName 
              managedObjectModel:nil 
                        delegate:self];
objectStore.delegate = self;
objectStore.cacheStrategy = [RKInMemoryManagedObjectCache new];

// Set up the event mapping (in my case, this is an XML file)
RKManagedObjectMapping *eventsMapping = [RKManagedObjectMapping mappingForEntityWithName:kEntityEvents 
                                                                    inManagedObjectStore:objectStore];
[eventsMapping mapKeyPath:@"contact" toAttribute:@"contact"];
[eventsMapping mapKeyPath:@"startDate" toAttribute:@"startDate"];
[eventsMapping mapKeyPath:@"endDate" toAttribute:@"endDate"];
[eventsMapping mapKeyPath:@"icon" toAttribute:@"icon"];
[eventsMapping mapKeyPath:@"location" toAttribute:@"location"];
[eventsMapping mapKeyPath:@"name" toAttribute:@"name"];
[eventsMapping mapKeyPath:@"notes" toAttribute:@"notes"];
[eventsMapping mapKeyPath:@"section" toAttribute:@"section"];
[eventsMapping mapKeyPath:@"url" toAttribute:@"url"];
eventsMapping.primaryKeyAttribute = @"name";

[objectManager.mappingProvider registerMapping:eventsMapping 
                               withRootKeyPath:@"root.events.event"];

// Added for RestKit upgrade from 0.9 to 0.10 to delete orphans (records not in GET)
[objectManager.mappingProvider setObjectMapping:eventsMapping 
                         forResourcePathPattern:@"data.xml" 
                          withFetchRequestBlock:^NSFetchRequest *(NSString *resourcePath) {
                              return [Events fetchRequest];
                          }];

// Load the opjects from XML file
[[RKObjectManager sharedManager] loadObjectsAtResourcePath:@"data.xml" 
                                                  delegate:self];
```

Comment: What did you set kBaseUrlString to to load the local data.xml file?